# Access object created on new thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, object

I have an application that runs a new thread to show a taskbar icon. Now I just can't figure out how I can call the TaskbarIcon (this is created on the new thread) from my main thread to show a balloon tip.

The code I have right now is:

```
public class NotificationHelper
{
    private TaskbarIcon notifyIcon { get; set; }

    public NotificationHelper()
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(OnLoad);
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); //Set the thread to STA
        thread.Start();
    }

    public void ShowNotification(string text)
    {
        notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip("Demo", text, notifyIcon.Icon);
    }

    public void OnLoad()
    {
        notifyIcon = new TaskbarIcon();
        notifyIcon.Icon =
            new Icon(@".\Icon\super-man-icon.ico");
        //notifyIcon.ToolTipText = "Left-click to open popup";
        notifyIcon.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    private void ShowBalloon()
    {
        notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip("Demo", Message, notifyIcon.Icon);
    }
}
```

And when I try to call 'ShowNotification("foobar");' I get this exception:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

The reason why I have 'while(true){}' in 'Onload()' is that I need the thread to be running until I close my application.

Comment: Why are you starting a new thread to show the `NotifyIcon`?

Comment: Because im trying to show it from class library what is not running on STA thread.

Comment: Your class library shouldn't be handling UI, most likely. But even if it must, you should just pass in the context of a `Form` object and use that to marshal the creation of the NotifyIcon to the UI thread.

Comment: In my experience, class libraries should know nothing at all about UI. Instead, the UI "uses" them and then shows you something based on the results.

Comment: Thats all true, but the UI is third party application and all what it knows is how to run mine class library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main thread, create a dispatcher with:

```
Dispatcher dispatcher = System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
```

Pass it to your NotificationHelper:

```
Dispatcher FDispatcher;

public NotificationHelper(Dispatcher ADispatcher)
{
     FDispatcher = ADispatcher;
     //...
}
```

Show the balloon:

```
private void ShowBalloon()
{
    FDispatcher.invoke(new Action(() => {
        notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip("Demo", Message, notifyIcon.Icon);
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try locking notifyIcon and checking for null like this:

```
public class NotificationHelper 
{
    private readonly object notifyIconLock = new object();
    private TaskbarIcon notifyIcon { get; set; }      

    public NotificationHelper()     
    {         
        Thread thread = new Thread(OnLoad);         
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); //Set the thread to STA         
        thread.Start();
    }

    public void ShowNotification(string text)
    {
        lock (notifyIconLock)
        {
            if (notifyIcon != null)
            {
                notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip("Demo", text, notifyIcon.Icon);
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnLoad()
    {
        lock (notifyIconLock)
        {
            notifyIcon = new TaskbarIcon();
            notifyIcon.Icon =
                new Icon(@".\Icon\super-man-icon.ico");
            //notifyIcon.ToolTipText = "Left-click to open popup";
            notifyIcon.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }

    private void ShowBalloon()
    {
        lock (notifyIconLock)
        {
            if (notifyIcon != null)
            {
                notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip("Demo", Message, notifyIcon.Icon);
            }
        }
    }
}
```